# Confusion in how to start solving such problems

Tags: velocity, position, acceleration

A coordinate frame (2) is attached to a body with origin 02 at the position [x(t) y(t) z(t)] transpose from the base frame (1). Apart from translation. the frame is rotating about the x1 axis by an angle theta(t). What is the velocity of the point P which is at the position 1 unit from 02, along the y2 axis?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.